# Live Reload in Gulp-Connect throwing: listen EADDRINUSE :::8080

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-connect

I'm having the same problem as in this question (the answer doesn't work):

[Gulp-connect shows an error 'listen EADDRINUSE' 8080](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35977029/gulp-connect-shows-an-error-listen-eaddrinuse-8080)

I'm trying to get the gulp-connect liveReload option to work. The script loads:

```
Server started http://localhost:8080
[12:01:20] LiveReload started on port 35729
```

But then when I modify a html file in the project and hit save, I receive this error:

```
events.js:182
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8080
```

I have tried changing ports as recommended (both localhost and liveReload) but it doesn't change anything.

Code:

```
gulp.task('default', ['connect', 'watch'], function () {

browserify({
    entries: ['./builds/development/js/main.js'],
    debug: true
  })
  .bundle()
  .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('myDestination'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('myFileSources', ['default']);
});

gulp.task('connect', function(){
    connect.server({
        root: "myRoot",
        port: 8080, // 8081
        livereload: true // {port:35730}
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simply because your port `8080` **is already occupied by another running server**. Simply change the port with something available like `3XXX` or `9XXX`.